# How to make Excel calculate average for a group of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set where the number of values I have in each category in different. I want excel to automatically group values in a category and calculate the average. For example, see below:

Screenshot of the example data set

[image]

As you can see X1 has three values, whereas X2 has just one value and X3 has three values. I want excel to return averages for each category as displayed in "Average" Column.

Comment: Normally you'd use `AVERAGEIF` but your data is bad.  You'll need to fill in the first column so every row is associated with its X# value.  Continuing to use bad data will only cause worse and worse problems down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a helper column before the category column, you can have something like this:

[image]

Here are the formulas used:

[image]

The helper column will number the rows according to the category and increase the numbering in each change of category. The average column uses the averageif formula which makes use of the numbering as the criteria.

You can further format the helper column so that it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The indirect function can help ... 
If you know the next label in Column 1 you can do this ...

*Assuming Category is Column A and X1 is Row 2*

Range("C1") `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":B"&MATCH("X2",A:A)-1))`
Range("C2") `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":B"&MATCH("X3",A:A)-1))`
For your last...
Range("C3") `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B7:B"&COUNTA(B:B)))`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @tigeravatar, [fill in the gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365283/1505120) as mentioned under *supplementary* and you will have data that is much easier to work with. For example, just apply Subtotal (At each change in: `Category`, Use function `Average`, Add subtotal to : `Value`).

Or, apply [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642).